# How to create a div with jQuery accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
</script>
```

To get the effect of expand/collapse. (If you know a better plugin or method, pls notice me)

I have this div: `<div id ="accordion"></div>`

And this code to create a button inside that div. (dont worry about the content of button)

```
$('#button_submit').click(function() 
{
$("#accordion").append(
$("<button id=saved"+j+">").click(function() {
drawChart.apply(null, myArray);
}).html("<b>Start date:</b>"+""+myArray[0]+"\n<b>End date:</b>"+myArray[1]+"\n<b>Chart type:</b>"+myArray[2]+"")
);
```

My question is, how to create/format div accordion to have this effect [accordion effect jquery](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) .

being that the `<button id=saved"+j+">` should appear inside the `sections`.

Cheers

Comment: Then put it in the sections, not the main div, lol. `$("#accordion > div").append( ...`

Comment: See my updated answer, i included a fully working example

Comment: Updated answer, did you mean something like [***this***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/8Y67K/13/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Updated** *with Example*  <sub>In other words, Tested and Working</sub>

Here's the code you need. The problem, as I mentioned before is you are adding the button to the main div and not to the sections.

## **jsFiddle (working example)**




## **Alt Example (possibly cleaner)**




## **This one allows adding new accordion pieces (with button inside)**

- *NOTE*: The tricky part to this last one is that you must destroy the accordion and recreate it, so if you have specific options for creating the accordion, you might want to wrap them in a seperate function and call it right after the destroy

> Script

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();

    $("#accordion .ui-accordion-content").each(function(i) {
        $(this).append(
            $("<button />")
                .prop("id", "saved"+j+">")
                .html("<b>Start date:</b>"+""+myArray[0]+"\n<b>End date:</b>"+myArray[1]+"\n<b>Chart type:</b>"+myArray[2])
                .on("click", function(e) {
                    drawChart.apply(null, myArray);
                })
        );
    });
})
```

Be sure your HTML Layout is correct.

> Example HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
        suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
        lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
        mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#accordion > div")`, when I put this nothing appears. It only shows something when is `$("#accordion")`, but ofc dont do what our we looking for.

Comment: @skdnewbie then use my second suggestion for a jQuery selector `$(".ui-accordion-content").each(...`, altho, if your HTML is set right, then there is no reason for the first suggestion not to work. I think you might need a better understanding of JS/jQuery and HTML layout. Please rereview the API and see how the work is being done. http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: I've read it already. But the examples are always about already defined <h3>..<div>..In my case, I need to build that (those <div>) at the same (barely before) time I create the button, to stuck myButton in there. Im sorry, I even dont know if it is possible :s

Comment: eg: buttonX trigger my button creater function , then <h3>Some text</h3><div>button_1 is built</div> should be created. UPDATED code with that trigger

Comment: @skdnewbie I'm trying my best to help, tho I'm still a little unsure of what you mean, can you lay a better example? maybe draw some sort of diagram?

Comment: our misunderstood is about that I dont have the html content. My point is create the html and the button everytime `$('#button_submit').click(function()` is pushed.

Comment: @skdnewbie See my last example listed above. The key to adding a new panel to an accordion is the last line: `$("#accordion").accordion("destroy").accordion();` Keep in mind, if you have any `options` for your accordion, you can save them to a variable in Object format and recall them every time you `recreate` the accordion: `var opts = { autoHeight: false }; $("#accordion").accordion("destroy").accordion(opts);` You might would think the `refresh` command would do this, but it only `re-sizes ` the accordion. To add a new panel you must destroy and `re-initialize` it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simple Accordion plugin..

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-accordion-menu-jquery/

```
$("#accordion > li > div").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
$(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});

$('#accordion ul:eq(0)').show();
```

Comment: I dunno, jQueryUI's accordion plugin seems ezier

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI Accordion expects a specific HTML structure.

> The underlying HTML markup is a series of headers (H3 tags) and content divs so the content is usable without JavaScript.

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
        suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can't just slap a button in there an expect it to work.  You could put a button in the sections.

Comment: "You could put a button in the sections." This was my question